# 'casperjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command (Windows 7)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I install PhantomJS and CapserJS. I can run phantom JS just fine from CMD, but casperjs isn't working. I added both of them to my path... I have Python 3.4.1 installed on my computer.

Comment: Given the number of typos in your question and its title, I'd start by checking that I typed things correctly.

Comment: Also, "isn't working" won't get you any answers. Give us the details of what you typed (exactly), the error message you got, the OS you're using, how you installed things, etc.

Comment: I changed the 1 spelling error in the title. Sorry, I was typing quickly while looking at the CMD

Comment: "Isn't working" means I typed casperjs into cmd after adding the path

Comment: Again, what did you type exactly, and what exactly was the result. What you are saying is the equivalent of "I tried to get to Rome but didn't get there. Why?".

Comment: I didn't think I could be any clearer. I extracted phantomjs and casperjs in C:/ and added them to path. I opened command prompt and typed in "phantomjs" and it worked. When I tried typing "casperjs" in CMD it gave the message above.

Comment: Have you restarted `cmd`? What does `path` say? Did you correctly include `casperjs\batchbin` (not `casperjs\bin`) in your path?

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't have /batchbin

Comment: you can try to install it globally with `-g`, I've seen it added to the path this way automatically